# How to deduct product quantity from database after order is proceed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dapper

I have 2 asp.net WebForms, WebForm1 contains a button that redirects into WebForm2 which contains a contact form that needs to be filled to proceed an order.
I have a drop down list in it that is connected to the database, and depending on which product a button on the WebForm1 is clicked, the current quantity is displayed from the specific product from the database.
After the ordering, I need to decrease/deduct the product quantity from the database depending on how many products on the drop down list were selected.

**How to decrease the product quantity after the order is proceed?**

Here is the code that fills several TextBoxes, inserts currency and fills the drop down list "Quantity" depending on which product on the WebForm1 the button is clicked:

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string productName = Request.QueryString["productname"];
        txt_product13.Text = productName;

        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
    { "@ProductName", productName }
          };

        var parameters = new DynamicParameters(dictionary);
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductsDB WHERE ProductName = @ProductName";
            var product = connection.QuerySingle<Product>(sql, parameters);
            CultureInfo EuroCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
            txt_productprice.Text = product.Price.ToString("c", EuroCulture);

            for (int i = 1; i <= product.Quantity; i++)
            {
                dropdownlist1.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
            }

        }
     
    }
```

For now I have this code for decreasing, can you tell where is my mistake and why does it not decrement the quantity from database?

```
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        string productName = Request.QueryString["productname"];
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var sql = "UPDATE ProductsDB SET Quantity = WHERE ProductName = @ProductName" + dropdownlist1.SelectedValue + "'";
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: The query isn't working, because it's not valid: `UPDATE ProductsDB SET Quantity = WHERE ProductName = @ProductName" + dropdownlist1.SelectedValue + "'"`. You can't set the value of a column to be a `WHERE` clause, and concatenating the value of your drop down list to the variable's name makes little sense too.

Comment: Learn to properly parameterize your database queries.

Comment: I fixed the query, but it decrements only 1 whatever value I select from the drop down list. Why? `var sql = "UPDATE ProductsDB SET Quantity = Quantity - " + dropdownlist1.SelectedValue + " WHERE ProductName = @ProductName";`

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE ProductsDB SET Quantity = WHERE ProductName = @ProductName" + dropdownlist1.SelectedValue + "'".

should be something like...

UPDATE ProductsDB SET Quantity = **(oldValue - QtyOrdered)** WHERE ProductName = @ProductName" + dropdownlist1.SelectedValue + "'".